# Cursor.getInt() throws CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, sqlite

[image: Apologies to those with bandwidth problems.]

So, I have a method in a `SQLiteDatabaseHelper` class that reads a number and returns a boolean value, as the above picture shows. However, executing the code just throws this exception:

```
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:84)
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at com.mowdownDevelopments.nagTasks.NagTasksDatabaseHelper.isTaskChecked(NagTasksDatabaseHelper.java:239)
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at com.mowdownDevelopments.nagTasks.NagTaskListFragment.onPrepareActionMode(NagTaskListFragment.java:184)
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onPrepareActionMode(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:1181)
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$ActionModeImpl.invalidate(ActionBarImpl.java:713)
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.startActionMode(ActionBarImpl.java:405)
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.startActionMode(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:178)
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.startActionMode(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:50)
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at com.mowdownDevelopments.nagTasks.NagTaskListFragment.onListItemClick(NagTaskListFragment.java:62)
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:58)
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-28 19:49:45.881: E/AndroidRuntime(355):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Which points to the problem being here:

```
public boolean isTaskChecked(long taskID){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columns = {ID, CHECKED};
        Cursor c = db.query(TASKS, columns, "_id="+taskID, null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        int boolAsInt = c.getInt(1); //This line is throwing.
        //db.close();
        c.close();
        if (boolAsInt==1) {
            return true;
        } else if (boolAsInt==0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            panicButton();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

As the picture shows, performing the query via ADB returns it just fine. (I used a generic query there, but `select _id, ischecked from tasks where _id=1;` worked fine as well.) I don't get why it's saying I'm requesting index 0 when the code clearly is asking for column index 1, and how the size is 0 when performing the queries within a shell gives me something that works (and isn't size zero-based anyway?). Can anyone help me debug this?

**[EDIT:]** So, it turns out that the problem was that, for this particular issue, was that I was always passing -1 from a different class. I apologize for wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
if(c.moveToFirst()){
    int boolAsInt = c.getInt(1);
}
```

The cursor might be empty, so you have to check this before trying to get any values from it.
moveToFirst() returns false in case the cursor is empty so the if won't be entered and you won't get the exception anymore

The reasons for empty cursors is that the SQL query returned an empty result set. If you are sure you should've gotten a non-empty set check again the query.

Comment: I've gotten this error using a `rawquery` that matches the SQL query in the question, with the obvious substitution of a number for a variable. I shouldn’t be getting an empty set.

Answer (score 0):

getInt method's parameter is index, so if you're trying to get the first column of the query, you should put 0.